# Display MySQL data using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am making a small script where I  enter form data into a database table when I press submit.

What I want to do is to show the added data on the next page i.e. app.post for /form

at the moment I am getting only a employee ......with salary ..... added 
But I want to display the whole row of the data I just added.

Now, how do I do that?
here's the code for server.js which i use to run the app.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'employees'
});


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function (req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
});

app.get('/add-employee.html',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/add-employee.html'));
});

app.post('/add-employee.html',function(req,res){
    res.status(200).send();
    console.log('employee '+req.body.name + ' added');
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});

app.post('/form',function (req,res){
    //employee details from add-employee.html page
var name=req.body.name;
var designation = req.body.designation;
var pan = req.body.pan;
var aadhar = req.body.aadhar;
var bank = req.body.bank;
var salary = req.body.salary;
var allowance = req.body.allowance;
var esi = req.body.esi;
var uan = req.body.uan;

var details = {name:name,designation:designation,pan:pan,aadhar:aadhar,
    bank:bank,salary:salary,allowance:allowance,esi:esi,uan:uan};

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO employee_details SET ?',details,function(err,result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(query.sql);
}); 

connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee_details',function(err,rows){
  if(err) throw err;

  console.log('Data received');
  console.log(rows);
});


res.status(200).send('employee ' + name + 'with salary of '+salary+ ' added');
});




app.get('/add-company.html',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/add-company.html'));
});

app.get('/style.css',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/style.css'));
});

app.get('/main.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/main.js'));
});

app.get('/cmain.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/cmain.js'));
});

var port=8080;
app.listen(8080,function(req,res){
   console.log(`Payroll app listening on port ${port}!` );
});
```

I am able to see the rows from the select query in the console.
But the problem Is I dont know how to display that on the page itself.
how do I do that?

Comment: Your select query returing only one row?

Comment: no, actually I add the details of one employee and after I press submit I want it to show up on the page .i.e the details of the employee I added or it will do even if all the employee details show up. 
but it's not showing up at the moment, even though It is getting added to the database. I have checked that

Comment: your result object inf function(err, result) returned from the insert query might got the inserted obect. do console.log that

Comment: hmm. let me try that.

Comment: yes, that did help. I can see the rows in the console.
But, how do I display it on the page itself instead of seeing it in the console?

Comment: let me create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO employee_details SET    ?',details,function(err,result){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}
else{
   res.status(200).send(result);
}
});
```

Remove the below part this will send a result from where you called this api and you can display that result

Answer (score 1):

You need to select after insert.
Pay attention to the queries are async.

```
 var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO employee_details SET ?',details,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(query.sql);

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee_details',function(err,rows){
      if(err) throw err;

      console.log('Data received');
      console.log(rows);
      res.status(200).send('employee ' + name + 'with salary of '+salary+ ' added');
    });
    });
```

Comment: @faraz No. You call async function in a series. `connection.connect`, `connection.query` are async. You should call `query` inside `connection` callback. And for specific, when you call insert query, you don't wait for result of the query and call fetch query. Sometimes your fetch query maybe get result prior to insert query. SO you should ensure that your insert query run successfully then call fetch query. And you should ensure you fetch query then send response back to client